# Filter with wildcard

Tags: quality-center, hp-alm

I'm trying to filter the description.
All the posts I'm trying to get start with "FoG" or "F&G".

I can filter on "FoG*" or "F&G*". But can I search on "F.G*" where dot is one character of any kind?
Or "FoG*|F&G*" *<- this does not work*, but what I mean is filter on one or the other.

Is there any option to filter to get both "FoG" and "F&G"?

Comment: regular expression . represents a wild card, F.G should get you both FoG and F&G, here, experiment with your expressions, https://regex101.com/

Comment: I can't get the filter to work with regex and searching for it I find other answers saying HP QC does not accept regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this condition:

```
"FoG*" Or "F&G*"
```

ALM search does not support regular expressions. The expression above will return you all the records which start from `FoG` and from `F&G`

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! I did not expect to use "or" like that in the filter.